# Swift 5 - do something in app after some event inside embeded WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift

I am having iOS (Swift 5) app where user can click register button. This button open registration page from site in WKWebView (inside popover), user should complete onsite registration here, and when he finished registration I need to have a way to interract with my app (for example show message that registration in OK and close popover, to go back to app login screen). Of course I have access to site code and can modify something here if needed.

How can I do this? And how I can send back some data from webpage (for example variables and values) back to app?

As I understand in easy way I can somehow control what page url is visited in WKWebView, and when user reached "thankyou" page after registration do something (but I don't know Swift 5 code how to do this), but for some other pages I need to send some variables and values back from webpage (for ex. using JavaScript) back to my app. Is this possible and how to do this in Swift 5?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript Interface:

First of all, enable javascripts and add `WKScriptMessageHandler` delegate to your ViewController.

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {      
 webView.configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true
} else {
 webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
}
```

**If you want to catch some data from the website**, add UserContentController to your webView configuration:
`webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "getData")`

If your app got the getData message, you can handle it:

```
extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "getData" {
           print(message.body) // <- Here you get the body if the message
           //Do something with the datas
        }
    }
}
```

On the website (JS), you can call it simply
`window.webkit.messageHandlers.getData.postMessage('anyString');`

**If you want to execute JS code on the site from Swift**, it's easy as well:

```
func sendJS(param1: String) {
    let javascript = "callThisFunction('\(param1)')"
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascript, completionHandler: nil)
}
```